# Unexpected Output in C++ while printing newline character

Tags: c++

Anyone knows why it happens when I print a newline after printing out marks then the output is unexpected. When I remove it, the program works fine and gives an expected apart from a newline.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int sum(int[], int);
int max(int*, int);
int main()
{
    int marks[5] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    cout << marks << "\n";
    cout << sum(marks, 5) << "\n";
    cout << max(marks, 5) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
int sum(int arr[], int n)
{
    cout << arr << "\n";
    int total = 0;
    for (int i; i < n; i++) {
        total += arr[i];
    }
    return total;
}
int max(int* ptr, int n)
{
    cout << ptr << "\n";
    int max = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        max = max > *(ptr + i) ? max : *(ptr + i);
    }
    return max;
}
```

[Output when the newline is printed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AtpLf.png)

[Output when the newline printing statement is removed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTBnn.png)

Comment: Could you please indent your code in a reasonable manner?  Also please don't post images of text, there's a reason why you're not trusted to post pictures here inline.

Comment: I fixed the code formatting. See the console.log() example for an easy way to format in the future: [https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: Note that `*(ptr + i)` and `ptr[i]` do exactly the same thing. The latter is easier to read.

Answer (score 3):

In your `sum()` function's for loop, variable `i` is not initialized, which means its value is not predictable. Via `gdb` on my machine, when `"\n"` is not printed, `i` is `32767`; when `"\n"` is printed, `i` **happens** to be `0`.

Comment: That's why compiler warnings are so useful

Comment: @MatG alas not all compilers catch this bug. Warnings are great but one needs to be vigilant.